# Insert element '0' in the middle of the queue, if the number of elements is even, and if it is odd, then after the middle element

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>  // подключили библиотеку queue
 
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");
  queue <int> q;  // создали очередь q
  
  cout << "Пользователь, пожалуйста введите 7 чисел: " << endl;
 
  for (int h = 0; h < 7; h++) { 
    int a; 
    
    cin >> a;
      
    q.push(a);  // добавляем в очередь элементы
  }
  
  cout << endl;
  cout << "Самый первый элемент в очереди: " << q.front() << endl;  // выводим первый
                                                                   // элемент очереди
  q.pop();  // удаляем элемент из очереди
    
  cout << "Новый первый элемент (после удаления): " << q.front() << endl;
    
  if (!q.empty()) cout << "Очередь не пуста!";  // проверяем пуста ли очередь (нет)
    
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

I want to insert '0' in the middle of the queue,  if the number of elements is even, and if it is odd, then after the middle element.

Comment: *Why* do you want to insert something in the middle of a queue? Why are you using a queue in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queue jumping is not allowed. A queue does not have an operation for inserting into the middle. As such, queue is probably not a good choice of data structure for your use case.

In order to achieve the corresponding result, following algorithm can be used:

```
repeat initial size / 2 times:
    push front element of the old queue into a new one
    pop element from the front of the old queue
push the new element
repeat until queue is empty
    push front element of the old queue into a new one
    pop element from the front of the old queue
```

Note that this has linear complexity.

Comment: can you explain it with coding sample in c++ or java I greatly appreacited

Answer (score 1):

With a `queue` you cannot do that as that's an invalid operation. But if you really need to do that you could make two queues and in the second one push the elements of the first queue until middle or one after middle position is reached and then push a '0' and then push rest of the elements.

Or you should consider a data structure that allows you to insert in middle if queue is not a compulsion!